# Custom router/wi-fi access

Tags: router, authentication, wifi

I'm looking for a way to restrict wi-fi access to devices on our network. I've got an external server running on an outside network which should authenticate the user access to the network.

What router solutions are available to setup such an infrastructure where I can build a custom offsite web application which new users ends up on and grants network access locally?

I guess I'm looking for something similar to what you get at hotels and public/payed wifis.

Answer (score 1):

I know OpenWRT will do Captive Portals. I think dd-WRT will do them too. Many commercial products exist as well.

Comment: There are many custom mods of DD-WRT that do exactly what you are looking for.  Check here: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-howto/30150-how-to-build-an-open-source-wi-fi-hotspot-with-dd-wrt